# checkboxradio is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery mobile 1.3.1 (js & css) in my web app. When I call checkboxradio to uncheck all the checkboxes, its throwing the exception "checkboxradio is not a function"

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

When I try the same as a sample app, it works.

The problem is: the function inside jQuery mobile 1.3.1.js file is not getting called. I do see the jQuery mobile 1.3.1.js in the scripts loaded in firebug.

Please advise on how to find out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Can you please set up a jsfiddle or maybe post some more of your code?

Comment: Maybe you didn't include that widget.

Comment: Replace `.attr` with `.prop`.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for checkbox uncheck script http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/dzckn/2/

## JQUERY

```
$("#checklisttable input").each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```